# How can i export MS SQL into MySql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i export large tables from MS SQL into MySql table. Please note that the tables a large and.

I tried the mysql migration toolkit that is in MySql Workbench but i could not establish connectons to the SQL server

Please advise me on the best way to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: export to file, import from file?

Comment: @MikeC.: Agreed. For one-off's like this brute force is often best, instead of make-working an automated solution.

Answer (score 0):

One method of doing it (if it really is a lot of data and a lot of tables): creating a linked server in SQL Server and using it to push data into MySQL.

[This article gives step-by-step instructions to create the linked server.](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mysql-linked-server-on-sql-server-2008)

ANd then just run queries against your tables like so:

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (<LINKED SERVER>, 'SELECT * FROM MySQL_Table') 
SELECT * FROM dbo.SQL_Table
```

Comment: I think your answer is what I need but I have been trying over and over to follow instruction and it seems that it is not working for me.  id there a better instruction on how to set them up when I can connect to SQL from MySql? so I am going to move tables from MS SQL server to MySql

Comment: What isses are you having?